# How to use list elements to query data from a database using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, dbplyr

I use `dplyr` (version 0.8.3) to query data. The query includes parameters that are defined in the beginning of the query, as shown in the first reprex below. On top of that, I want to collect the parameters in a list, as shown the second reprex. The first and second examples, which query data from a dataframe, work fine. However, when I want to query data from a database using parameters saved in a list, the SQL translation produces a non-working SQL that cannot be used to query data from a database.

Is there a way to incorporate list entries into a `dplyr` pipeline to query data from a database?

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(RSQLite)

# 1. Data frame: value 
a <- 1
mtcars %>% filter(vs == a) # Works

# 2. Data frame: list value
input <- list()
input$a <- 1
mtcars %>% filter(vs == input$a) # Works

# 3. Database: value and list value
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars, "mtcars", temporary = FALSE)
db_mtcars <- tbl(con, "mtcars")

db_mtcars %>% filter(vs == a)          %>% show_query() %>% collect() # Works
db_mtcars %>% filter(vs == input$a)    %>% show_query() %>% collect() # Does not work
db_mtcars %>% filter(vs == input[1])   %>% show_query() %>% collect() # Does not work
db_mtcars %>% filter(vs == input[[1]]) %>% show_query() %>% collect() # Does not work
```

The background of my question is that I want to process and analyze data in a `shiny` app. I find it easier to develop the code for processing data outside the app and then include the code in the app afterwards. However, this task becomes increasingly difficult with a growing number of inputs. For development, my idea was to define a list named "input" such that I can copy and paste the code into the app. However, I stumble over the problem decribed above. Suggestions for an alternative development workflow are very welcome, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `dplyr>=1.0.0` you need to `{{embrace}}` values, see [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) :

```
db_mtcars %>% filter(vs == a)          %>% show_query() %>% collect() # Works
db_mtcars %>% filter(vs == {{input$a}})    %>% show_query() %>% collect() # should work
db_mtcars %>% filter(vs == {{input[1]}})   %>% show_query() %>% collect() # should work
db_mtcars %>% filter(vs == {{input[[1]]}}) %>% show_query() %>% collect() # should work
```

for `dplyr <1.0.0` you can use the [bang bang](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/) `!!` operator : `!!input$a`.

Comment: I get the error: "Error: `arg` must be a symbol Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred." 

Tracing the error gives: 
<error/rlang_error>
`arg` must be a symbol
Backtrace:
  8. dplyr::filter(...)
 10. rlang::quos(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

I use `dplyr` version 0.8.3, which is older than the version of the documentation. Unfortunately, I cannot update the version.

Comment: for older dplyr versions, try with [bang bang](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/) : `!!input$a`